# Excel Power Query with VBA - Textdata with new sheet for each data

Tags: excel, vba, text, import, powerquery

I need help with Excel VBA. I want to import some text-files into my Excel sheets and I want to automate this with VBA, because I have lot of Data to import and this would save me time.

All text files are build the same. I want to import one into a sheet, then create a new sheet and import the next file in the new sheet. This process should go on until all the data is importet. So every textfile needs a new Excel sheet. And all of this should work automatically with VBA. I just want to start the makro and then it does its work. The problem is, that I am not able to build such an VBA code. But I tried.

Here is what I already have:

```
Sub A()
   With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
      If .Show Then Sheets.Add , Sheets(Sheets.Count), , .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Sub

Sub B()

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    .AllowMultiSelect = True

    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\Thoma\Desktop\Test\*.txt"

    If .Show Then

        For Each f In .SelectedItems

            Sheets.Add , Sheets(Sheets.Count), , f

        Next f

    End If

End With

End Sub
```

This code opens the Windows Explorer and then you can choose several textfiles. Then it will load every file in a new Excel sheet. The problem is, that it does not use Power Query, so there is no data connection to the files in the folder and I cant refresh them. Also it does import all data to the first column, which is not good because it needs to be in seperated columns.

Also I have this code:

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="aacg us", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Quelle = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\Thoma\Downloads\Neuer Ordner\aacg.us.txt""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=10, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Höher gestufte Header"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Quelle, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Analysierte JSON"" = Table.TransformColumns(#""Höher gestufte Header"",{{""<OPEN>"", Json.Docum" & _
        "ent}, {""<HIGH>"", Json.Document}, {""<LOW>"", Json.Document}, {""<CLOSE>"", Json.Document}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Analysierte JSON"""
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""aacg us"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [aacg us]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "aacg_us"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

I created this one with the makro recorder. It opens one file with the name accg.us and creates an Power Query table. After doing this it will add a new sheet. The problem with this one is, that it will only load the file accg.us and not the complete folder.

So I need to combine booth somehow and I dont know how.

Here is some sample data:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hMPO9LbZwBV4pEdeyCv2Cbwp6Sr8vHM6